# "in on one of the planetary systems" - should "on" be removed here?

Tags: prepositions

> For the second time, the James Webb Space Telescope (JWST) has looked
> for and failed to find a thick atmosphere **on** an exoplanet **in on
> one of the most exciting planetary systems known.** Astronomers
> report1 today that there is probablyno tantalizing atmosphere on the
> planet TRAPPIST-1 c, just as they reported months ago for its
> neighbour TRAPPIST-1 b.

[Source: Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01983-1)

The second "on" in the first sentence appears to be a typo and should be removed. I am not absolutely sure.

Should it be removed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a proofreading error

Comment: Yes it's an error